# Why is this formula returning 5H and 60M instead of 5H 0M?

Tags: formula, datetime

Here is the source formula.

```
IF( 
    Step_1_Diff__c> 0 , 
    TEXT(
        FLOOR(MOD(Step_1_Diff__c* 24, 24))
    ) & "H " &
    TEXT(
        ROUND(MOD(Step_1_Diff__c* 24 * 60, 60), 0)
    ) & "M ", 
    "" 
)
```

Every time the Diff__c field = 02.1 or 5H the result is 5H 60M, instead of the correct 5H 0M. What am I missing????

Comment: Can you clarify which value of `Step_1_Diff__c` gives you 5H 60M? It is not 02.1, I think.

Comment: End_Time_step1__c-Start_Time_step1__c = 0.21
1/1/2016 1:00 PM-1/1/201 6:00 PM = 0.21

That is what the formula for Step_1_Diff__c returns

Comment: I created that formula in my org. Replaced the field name with the constant "0.21". Returns, properly, `5H 2M`.

Comment: 2M? Interesting. I thought it should be 5H 0M, right? I did that as well and yep, it returns 2M. Strange...

Comment: No, math says it's 5h 2m. But I found your problem. Working on the answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways around it. This is the one I prefer (I'll put the other one at the bottom)

This one will always round down the minutes... (i.e.: 4:59:59 will be 4:59) which perhaps is what you prefer.

```
IF( 
    Step_1_Diff__c > 0 , 
    TEXT(
        FLOOR(MOD(Step_1_Diff__c * 24, 24))
    ) & "H " &
    TEXT(
        FLOOR(MOD(Step_1_Diff__c * 24 * 60, 60)))
    ) & "M ", 
    "" 
)
```

**Alternative Answer**

This one will round to the nearest minute, which perhaps is what you prefer. I do think that 4:59:59 is 4:59, not 5:00.... at least when time is concerned.

```
IF( 
    Step_1_Diff__c > 0 , 
    TEXT(
        ROUND(MOD(Step_1_Diff__c * 24, 24),0)
    ) & "H " &
    TEXT(
        IF(ROUND(MOD(Step_1_Diff__c * 24 * 60, 60), 0)=60,0, ROUND(MOD(Step_1_Diff__c * 24 * 60, 60), 0))
    ) & "M ", 
    "" 
)
```

Explanation:

1) The bottom `ROUND` was changing minutes very close (but not quite) to a round hour to 60 (instead of 0). For Example: (i.e.: 4:59:59 will be 4:60). So, the IF on the rounding helps you with that

2) Because of the same issue, the top formula has to also be changed from `FLOOR` to `ROUND`.

Comment: Sebastian! Thank you my friend. I don't think I would have ever figured that out. The first formula is returning a syntax error however. Syntax error. Extra ',' (Related field: Formula) Formula #2 works great!

Answer (score 1):

From [**How to express the difference of 2 Date/Time fields in days,hours,mn format ?**](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004393&language=en_US):

```
/*check to see if D2subD1 is greater than zero*/
IF (D2subD1__c > 0,
  /*returns the number of days in D2subD1*/
 TEXT(FLOOR( D2subD1__c)) & " days " &
  /*returns the remaining number of hours in D2subD1*/
 TEXT(FLOOR( 24 * (D2subD1__c - FLOOR(D2subD1__c) ))) & " hours " &
  /*returns the remaining number of minutes in D2subD1*/
 TEXT(ROUND(60 * (ROUND( 24 * ( D2subD1__c - FLOOR(D2subD1__c) ),8) -   FLOOR(ROUND(24 * (D2subD1__c - FLOOR(D2subD1__c) ),8)) ),0)) & " mins"
, "")
```